# Use Python 3.4+ Regex to match up to, but not including a # symbol, plus a range of lowercase letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I would like to use Regex in Python 3.4+ to match a combination of the '#' symbol + the next lowercase letter. There's a bunch of obfuscating data in the strings that's making it tricky for me to do this in one clean line of regex. Here's an example string:

```
Stack #Overflow is a question and answer website for #professional and enthusiast programmers.
```

I'd like the regex here to match up to the word '#professional' (because it's lowercase), skipping over the '#Overflow' occurrence (because it's uppercase). After the operation I want to be left with:

```
professional and enthusiast programmers
```

or

```
#professional and enthusiast programmers
```

I can get it to match up to the first # with `^[^#]*`, but I'm not seeing a good way to put a range of chars in there to specify that the following character needs to be lowercase(a-z, etc).

My initial thought was to try `^[^#a-z]*`, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas of how to make this work with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for a "positive lookahead" -- an anchor which consumes no part of the string but makes an assertion about the characters afterwards

```
>>> s = 'Stack #Overflow is a question and answer website for #professional and enthusiast programmers.'
>>> re.search('#(?=[a-z])', s)
<re.Match object; span=(53, 54), match='#'>
```

the `(?=...)` part is the positive lookahead, asserting that the `#` is immediately followed by a lowercase character -- notice this matches the second `#` and not the first.  from here you can get the rest of the string:

```
>>> s[_.end():]
'professional and enthusiast programmers.'
```

`_` here being the last expression in the repl (you'd want to assign the match to a variable in your actual code)

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Is there any way to incorporate this into the re.sub method? Trying to do this as a clean one-liner. I tried this: ^#(?=[a-z]) to get it to start from the top and match "up to", but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually this seems to work. Let me know what you think:
^(.*?#(?=[a-z]))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pattern `r'#([a-z])(.*)'` with `re.search` to get the expected result

```
import re

line = "Stack #Overflow is a question and answer website for #professional and enthusias programmers."

matchObj = re.search(r'#([a-z])(.*)', line)

if matchObj:
   print("match string : ", matchObj.group())
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to match the target word itself('#professional'), but i'm trying to exclude and only get stuff before the word.